# Print a class output using numpy python array?

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, scipy

i have this class which build the classification features, by averaging the word vectors for all vectors in the text

```
class MeanEmbeddingVectorizer(object):
    def __init__(self, word2vec):
        self.word2vec = word2vec
        self.dim = len(word2vec.itervalues().next())

    def fit(self, X, y):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        return np.array([
            np.mean([self.word2vec[w] for w in words if w in self.word2vec]
                    or [np.zeros(self.dim)], axis=0)
            for words in X
        ])
```

so my question how to print the output of this class to screen or save it to a file
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a `print` statement at the end but you still need to create the attribute `word2vec`

```
import numpy as np

class MeanEmbeddingVectorizer(object):
    def __init__(self, word2vec):
        self.word2vec = word2vec
        self.dim = len(word2vec.itervalues().next())

    def fit(self, X, y):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        return np.array([
            np.mean([self.word2vec[w] for w in words if w in self.word2vec]
                    or [np.zeros(self.dim)], axis=0)
            for words in X
        ])
print(MeanEmbeddingVectorizer.fit("X", "Y", "Z"))
```

will give you the output

```
X
None
```

but if you run

```
print(MeanEmbeddingVectorizer.transform("X", "Y"))
```

you get

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'word2vec'
```